# How to use dependency injection in PHP?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am just starting to learn object-oriented PHP and ran into a little problem. A colleague told me that it is better to use dependency injection instead of inheriting the database class. I want to use dependency injection but I don't know how. I tried to use in the constructor but an error pops up:

> Fatal error: `Uncaught TypeError`: Argument 1 passed to `signIn::__construct()` must be an instance of database, array given, called in `C:\xampp\htdocs\messbox\index.php` on line 54 and defined in
> `C:\xampp\htdocs\messbox\klasy\sign_in.php:12`
> Stack trace:
> #0 `C:\xampp\htdocs\messbox\index.php(54)`: `signIn->__construct(Array)`
> #1 `{main}` thrown in `C:\xampp\htdocs\messbox\klasy\sign_in.php` on line 12

I hope someone will explain to me how to use it correctly.

```
<?php

class database {
  private $servername = "localhost";
  private $username = "root";
  private $password = "";
  private $dbname = "messbox";

  public function connect() {
    $this->servername = "localhost";
    $this->username = "root";
    $this->password = "";
    $this->dbname = "messbox";
    try {
      $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->servername . ";dbname=" . $this->dbname;
      $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      return $pdo;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }  
  }
}
?>
```

```
require_once('connect.php');
class signIn {
  private $data;
  private $errors = '';
  private $count;
  private $database;
  
  public function __construct(database $database) {
    $this->database = $database;
  }
  
  public function validate_login() {
    $val = trim($this->data['log']);
    if (empty($val)) {
        return $this->errors = "Field can not empty!";
    }
  }
  
  public function validate_password() {
    $val = trim($this->data['pass']);
    if (empty($val)) {
      return $this->errors = "Field can not empty!";
    }
  }
  
  public function ifexist() {
    $field1 = $this->data['log'];
    $field2 = $this->data['pass'];
    $sql = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where login = :login");
    $sql->bindParam(':login', $field1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->execute();        
    if ($sql->rowCount()) {
      header("location:./home.php");
      return $this->count = 10;
    } else {
      return $this->count = 2;
    }
  }
  
  public function setSession() {
    if ($this->licznik == 10) {
      $field1 = $this->data['log'];
      $sql = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where login = :login");
      $sql->bindParam(':login', $field1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $sql->execute();      
      while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        echo $_SESSION['login'] = $row['login'];
        $_SESSION['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];
        echo "<img src='".$row['avatar']."'/>";
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
        $_SESSION['number_phone'] = $row['number_phone'];
        $_SESSION['gender'] = $row['gender'];
        $_SESSION['birth_date']  = $row['birth_date'];
        $_SESSION['age'] = $row['age'];     
      }
    } else
      return "Not working";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd suggest you read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see some guidelines for creating a good question. Stating "an error pops up" is vague - include the exact error, including file and line, and it would be advisable to identify that line for us. That way we can identify the error more quickly.

Comment: All that being said, seems you need to learn more about how objects work. You try to connect using `$sql = $this->connect()->prepare...`. Your `signIn` class didn't inherit the `connect` method through injection. You need to make use of the property where you injected your `database` instance by calling `$this->database->connect()`. Any time you need to use something from that class you do it through `$this->database`.

Comment: sidenote, declare your class names in StudlyCaps, read all about this and more in [psr-1 basic coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/).

Answer (score 1):

You have injected the database class into your signIn class.

```
require_once('connect.php');
public function __construct(database $database) {
  $this->database = $database;
}
```

But the error is due to the below code.

```
$sql = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where login = :login");
```

You should be referring to the connect function with `$this->database`

```
$sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where login = :login");
```

Comment: I changed it, but now show me error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connect() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\messbox\klasy\sign_in.php:41 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\messbox\index.php(57): signIn->ifexist() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\messbox\klasy\sign_in.php on line 41

Comment: And now you've learned why method chaining is bad when its tied to state outside your code. The connect method is failing.